# How to import android github example with repositories and dependencies definitions

Tags: android, android-studio

I know there are similar questions like this but i'm new in android development and i need to learn how to import an example defining repositories and dependencies in the build.gradle project file.
After several tries i can't figure out which is the right way...

The example is this one https://github.com/neokree/MaterialNavigationDrawer

When i load the project in android studio i get an error "Configuration with name 'default' not found.", and it's ok.. i know that i have to modify the build.grandle file

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'it.neokree:MaterialNavigationDrawer:1.3.3'
}
```

But where i have to add/replace these rows? In the buildscript area? in the allprojects? i get "Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'" error or fix plugin version alert if i try to change something.

**original build.grandle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please update gradle version to 1.3.0

Comment: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0 ? Done but same errors...

Comment: You should probably be placing most dependencies (unless they're a classpath) in app/build.gradle instead

Comment: @fractalwrench also tried in app/build.grandle, same error "Configuration with name 'default' not found."

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in setting.gradle file in the MaterialNavigationDrawer project. As you can see

```
include ':app', ':MaterialNavigationDrawerModule'
```

it requires MaterialNavigationDrawerModule project to build. Go to New > Import Module and import MaterialNavigationDrawerModule.
 Update build.gradle in MaterialNavigationDrawer\app to

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "it.neokree.materialnavigationdrawer"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            //runProguard false
            //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile project(':MaterialNavigationDrawerModule')
}
```

Update build.gradle in MaterialNavigationDrawer\MaterialNavigationDrawerModule to

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName 'dev'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {

        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.1'

}
```

In MainActivity i deleted missing import

[image]

and rewrite Intent

[image]

to

[image]

Now it's working.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! I've tried and i've solved in a different way, because with your steps i get a plugin error, but were indeed useful for solve it. For make it run i've simple changed the "compile project(':MaterialNavigationDrawerModule')" string to "compile 'it.neokree:MaterialNavigationDrawer:1.3.3'" in the MaterialNavigationDrawer\app\build.grandle